# Magento: monitoring execution time of all cron jobs?

Tags: php, magento

I've inherited a Magento Enterprise 1.9-based website which has a lot of cron jobs running regularly.

These cron jobs are configured by third-party modules and aren't part of Magento's core.

One set of jobs deals with the exporting and importing of data files from Magento to a warehouse management system, and sometimes the cron jobs will get stuck in some kind of loop and will keep processing for hours when they should only take minutes.

I would like to somehow monitor how long these jobs are taking, but without modifying each script itself. Perhaps some kind of observer, if such a thing is possible?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also interested in more insight in these processes. One thing that might help a bit is the core_cron database table. It contains information on running cron scripts and some errors, but not too much.

Comment: FYI, this question is not necessarily a great fit with SO, which is why there is a [proposal at Area51 for a dedicated Magento StackExchange site (link)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=HFqQT3Qeb2X27y6ehRWkiw2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a script that does a formatted table created out of the **cron_schedule** table.

<s>I know about the usual thing about posting links, but MagentoCommerce.com probably isn't going away anytime soon and getting the code posting over here is a royal PITA. [So here's the link to a PHP script that reads cron_schedule and creates a full report.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/351010/)</s> See bottom for code. Go into the System Configuration cron setups and tell it to save the information for 24 hours.

[image]

You now can see everything that's being scheduled and everything that's been executed as in the following output samples.

[image]
[image]

Sorry about the MageBayvaporation on the link, I tried to move the most important stuff over here, but missed this one. Fortunately it's still in operation on one of the sites.

```
<?php

/******************************************************
 * Magento Log File Contents Monitor.
 * Released under the Digital Damnation Copyright
 * Free to do whatever the 7734 you want to do with it.
 * provided without warranty or support
 ******************************************************/

/***********************
 * Scan Magento local.xml file for connection information
 * Run out of password protected scripts/ directory
 ***********************/

if (file_exists('../app/etc/local.xml')) {

$xml = simplexml_load_file('../app/etc/local.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;

$tables = array(
   'dataflow_batch_export',
   'dataflow_batch_import',
   'log_customer',
   'log_quote',
   'log_summary',
   'log_summary_type',
   'log_url',
   'log_url_info',
   'log_visitor',
   'log_visitor_info',
   'log_visitor_online',
   'catalog_compare_item',
   'report_event',
   'report_compared_product_index',
   'report_viewed_product_index',
   'sales_flat_quote',
   'sales_flat_quote_address',
   'sales_flat_quote_address_item',
   'sales_flat_quote_item',
   'sales_flat_quote_item_option',
   'sales_flat_quote_payment',
   'sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate'
);

} 

else {
    exit('Failed to open ../app/etc/local.xml');
}

/** Get current date, time, UTC and offset **/

$date   = date("Y-m-d");
$time   = date("H:i:s T");
$offset = date("P");
$utc    = gmdate("H:i:s");

/***********************
 * Start HTML output
 ***********************/

echo '<html><head><title>Magento Log File Contents on ' . $date . ' ' . $time . '</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<style type="text/css">html {width: 100%; font-family:  Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}
body {line-height:1.0em; font-size: 100%;}
table {border-spacing: 1px;}
th.stattitle {text-align: left; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #101010;}
th {text-align: center; font-size: 90%; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; }
td {font-size: 90%; padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;}
</style>
</head><body>';

/** Output title, connection info and cron job monitor runtime **/

echo '<h2>Magento Log File Contents Report</h2><h3>Connection: '.$db['user'].'@'.$db['host'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;&nbsp;Database: ' . $db['name'] . '</h3>';
echo '<h3>Runtime: ' . $date . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' .$time . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $utc . ' UTC</h3>';
echo '<h4>Note: Your timezone offset is ' . $offset . ' hours from UTC</h4>';

/** Connect to database **/

$conn = mysql_connect($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass']);
@mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

/***********************
 * Get table record counts
 ***********************/

echo '<table><tbody><tr><th class="stattitle" colspan="2">Log Tables</th></tr>';
echo '<tr><th>Table</th><th>Row Count</th></tr>';

foreach($tables as $tblname) {
   $result  = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $db['pref'] . $tblname) or die(mysql_error());
   $numrows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $num     = $numrows[0];

   /* Table output */
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$db['pref'].$tblname.'</td>';
   echo '<td align="right">'.$num.'</td>'; 
   echo '</tr>';                 
}

echo '</tbody></table></body></html>';

/***********************
 * End of report
 ***********************/

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. It was very helpful in getting the trigger cron process to function. Web servers sometimes are weird little concoctions of pieces of paranoia and bubble gum wrappers at times. I've come across systems that refuse to run Magento's cron.sh from crontab so you end up directly triggering cron.php. Also, it's nice to see that enabling the cron section in the module setup xml is actually picking up its end of the board and triggering.

Comment: I managed to find a different source but I appreciate the effort of finding and adding the code :) It will surely help others.

Answer (score 3):

Basic insight into the scheduling and running of scheduled jobs in Magento can be gleaned from the `core_schedule` table. Note that entries are added and removed according to the settings **from System > Configuration > System > Cron Schedule**. Originating scheduled job configuration (class, method, and cron expression) can be determined from the `<crontab />` node in any given module's *config.xml*.

Many of these can be visualized and interacted with in the Admin by using [Fabrizio Branca's AOE_Scheduler module (link)](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html).

To capture performance (memory usage, start/stop times), it may be necessary to drop some logging calls in these cron-fired scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have a client that had the same concerns where they weren't seeing how long jobs were running and didn't have any good insight into what was happening in their cron.  There were some solutions out there but they didn't quite do what they wanted so I ended up building a small service I call the [Job Health Data Vault](https://vh.10n-software.com/).  It's free for anyone to use.