# Getting a CSV files and setting it to automatically upload to magento

Tags: php, sql, magento, csv

So let's say a file automatically gets updated with products or customers now we need a script to upload files to magento and to have that run daily. I have the code to upload but I have two questions.

1. How do we set this script to automatically run?...Cron?
2. Is there a better way to do this rather than this script?

   ```
      if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) 
         { 
         // the table fields
         $tbl_fields = array('customerCode', 'postCode,Name', 'Address1', 'Address2');
         //get the csv file 
         $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
         $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
         // get the first line into a fields map
         $csv_fields = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"');
         // we will insert only common fields
         $tbl_fields = array_intersect($tbl_fields,$csv_fields);
         // if there's not at least one common field, don't go on
         if(count($tbl_fields)>0)
           {
           // we need the table's field names as keys (see below)
           $tbl_fields = array_flip($tbl_fields);
          // now let's go after the data
           while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'))
             {
             $data=array_map('addslashes',$data); // apply addslashes() to all values 
             $data=array_combine($csv_fields,$data); // csv fields assoc (key=>value)
             $data=array_intersect_key($data,$tbl_fields); // discard redundant
             $tbl_fields_str=implode("`,`",array_keys($data));
             $tbl_vals_str=implode("','",array_values($data));
             $q="INSERT INTO `PowerFlex` (`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$tbl_vals_str')";
             mysql_query($q);
             }
           }

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd answer both questions with yes. Use Magento's Cron (it's bascially a wrapper around the normal cron daemon), setup is really simple, just add these lines to your config:

```
<config>
...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <unique_identifer>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 2 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>your_module/model::method</model>
                </run>
            </unique_identifer>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

The node cron_expr tells magento when to run, currently set to every day at 2 am. the model::method is the method it will execute. You can find more information on cron and also on how to setup magento to use your linux cron tab here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

To check whether your crontab is running, there was a SO question on it: [Magento: monitoring execution time of all cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195809/magento-monitoring-execution-time-of-all-cron-jobs)

Towards your second question: 
It's quite hard to say, whether there is a better way, I'd probably setup a model that represents the data that will be inserted. So I'd definitely change the INSERT INTO line to something like:

```
Mage::getModel('your_module/model')->setCustomerCode($customerCode)
     ->setPostCode(...)
     ->setName(...)
     ...
     ->save();
```

This enables you to force some constrains for the values your inserting (if you want) and also use Magentos framework (with logging, error handling, etc).

For more information about how to create a model see this blog post from magento:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

HTH!